# a build fail with gradle while trying to build an android app on android studio

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

ive been working on a project for 6 months now and suddenly today when i opened m android studio and wanted to start debugging my android app ive got an error ive never seen before. i seached and found that the problem is with the gradle version and jave version but there are both up to date. i searched online for a solution but didnt find anything. pls help(idk if this is connected but the last time it worked wasa righht before i installed git)

here is the error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\downloads\Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter-master\Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter-master\android\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'E:\downloads\Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter-master\Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter-master\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 64

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i was trying to build an android app thro android studio, and i got an error

Answer (score 0):

Newest versions are not always guaranteed to be compatible. Assuming you have identified the cause as being incompatibility between Java and Gradle, I would suggest consulting the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) in the official Gradle page.

Without more information, such as the exact versions and a copy of your build scripts, it's challenging to provide specific recommendations.